Newton root finding and preserving automatic differentiation.
I am applying Newton's root solving algorithm. Suppose the example problem below, solving for $g$ with fixed parameter, $s$:
$$ f(g;s) = g^2 - s = 0, \qquad g_{i+1}=g_i - \frac{f(g_i;s)}{\frac{df}{dg}(g_i;s)} $$
Clearly this has the solution:
$$ g= \sqrt{s}, \qquad \frac{dg}{ds} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{s}}, \qquad \frac{d^2g}{ds^2} = \frac{-1}{4s^{3/2}}  $$
When you search for "Newton Algorithm" and "Automatic Differentiation", the majority of the results/papers reference applying automatic differentiation to determine the derivative, $\frac{df}{dg}(g_i;s)$ at each step in the interation. I am not interested in this.
What I am interested in is a formal proof that the following process can capture the accurate resultant sensitivities (i.e. $\frac{dg}{ds}$ and $\frac{d^2g}{dx^2}$:

First converge to solution using floating point arithmetic.
Perform one more iteration using the current float iterate for $g_i$ and adding the AD variable sensitivity to $s$. This will capture 1st deriavtive sensitivity accurately.
To capture 2nd order sensitivity perform one further iteration.

Empirically in all my tests this has not failed and is exactly accurate, but I would be more comfortable with a proof.
For those interested in some abstract code which I have working according to the above definitions is...
def f_and_df(g, s):
    f = g ** 2 - s
    df = 2*g
    return f, df

result = newton_root(f_and_df, g0=1.0, args=(2.0,))
# result = 1.4142135.....

result = newton_root(f_and_df, g0=1.0, args=(Dual(2.0, vars=["s"]),))
# result = <Dual: 1.4142135, ("s"), [0.35355..]>

result = newton_root(f_and_df, g0=1.0, args=(Dual2(2.0, vars=["s"]),))
# result = <Dual2: 1.4142135, ("s"), [0.35355..], [-0.088388..]>

# Internal newton_root code
# # After float convergence
# # Final iteration method to preserve AD
f0, f1 = f(g1, *(*args, *final_args))
if isinstance(f0, (Dual, Dual2)) or isinstance(f1, (Dual, Dual2)):
    # Perform 1 extra iteration because of AD variable
    g1 = g1 - f0 / f1
if isinstance(f0, Dual2) or isinstance(f1, Dual2):
    # Perform a 2nd iteration because of order = 2
    f0, f1 = f(g1, *(*args, *final_args))
    g1 = g1 - f0 / f1
return g1


Can you explain why you need the extra iteration for the second order term?

Well thats part of my question. But my theory is that the the final (2nd order) quantity contains three values; the function value, the 1st deriv sensitivity and the 2nd deriv. The converged algorithm requires one iteration to exactly solve the 1st deriv value and it requires a 2nd iteration, re-incorporating that exact derivative to capture the second derivative. It cant derive both unknown quantities in one iteration.

This one of the primary ways of doing forward-mode sensitivity analysis with automatic differentiation. See for example https://github.com/JuliaDiff/ForwardDiff.jl

I have an answer in progress that works for the first order portion, but not for the second order. I think the problem is that I'm treating newton_root as doing only one iteration of the algorithm. Does your code work if you skip the first order invocation and just call the second order one? How many iterations of newton_root are being done, internally? Can you set the maximum number of iterations to just 1, and see if you still get the correct second derivative?

@whpowell96 thanks for the link. That is exactly the form of auto diff I have created except I have extended it to handle second derivatives. The link unfortunately does not give a proof of the convergence of algorthms, in this case Newton algorithm, but it is a good link none-the-less.

@AlexK after converging in float form performing one iteration will yield a second derivative of zero. I can confirm this. It only generates the second derivative after 2 iterations. I think I can just about prove the the first order case (maybe), but the second order case after 2 iterations is. I will try and add some code.

It only works after two iterations because the second derivative is the term that is quadratic in the dual number. Unless you have another data type to handle dual numbers squared, two iterations are required to pick up the second derivative terms, which is in line with the typical costs of adjoint methods like in the current answer.

The derivative of the solution wrt $s$ can be calculated independent of Newton iterations -- simply from the condition that $f(g;s)=0$. Please excuse the change in notation; I'll be using numerical subscripts for partial derivatives: $$
f(g(s),s)=0 \\
\tfrac {d}{ds} f(g(s),s)=0 \\
f_1(g(s), s) g'(s) + f_2(g(s), s) = 0\\
g'(s) = \frac{-f_2(g(s), s)}{f_1(g(s), s)}
$$
In your example, we have $g(s)=\sqrt{s}$ already solved; $f_1(g,s)=2g$ and $f_2(g,s)=-1$. Thus, $g'(s)=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{s}}$.
Using automatic differentiation of $f$, you could calculate partial derivatives $f_1$ and $f_2$ (with respect to $g$ and $s$) and apply the above formula to get the total derivative wrt $s$.
So what happens when you do as you did, and apply automatic differentiation to the Newton step? You have newton step $F$ and you're calculating its derivative rt $s$: $$
F(g_0,s)=g_0-\frac{f(g_0,s)}{f_1(g_0,s)}\\
\frac {d}{ds}F(g_0,s)=\frac{f(g_0,s)f_{12}(g_0,s)-f_1(g_0,s)f_2(g_0,s)}{f_1(g_0,s)^2}\\
\text{Since }f(g_0,s)=0\text{, this simplifies}\\
\frac {d}{ds}F(g_0,s)=\frac{-f_2(g_0,s)}{f_1(g_0,s)}
$$
This is the same answer as we got from the implicit definition of $g(s)$. That only works once you're fully converged, since it relies on $f(g_0,s)$ evaluating to zero. Moving on to the second derivative: $$
\tfrac {d}{ds}\left(f_1(g(s), s) g'(s) + f_2(g(s), s) \right)= 0\\
(f_{11}(g(s),s)g'(s)+f_{12}(g(s),s))g'(s)+f_1(g(s), s) g''(s)+f_{21}(g(s),s)g'(s)+f_{22}(g(s),s)=0\\
\text{Shorthand: }(f_{11}g'+f_{12})g'+f_1 g''+f_{21}g'+f_{22}=0\\
g''=-\frac{f_{11}g'^2+2f_{12}g'+f_{22}}{f_1} \text{ and using }g'=\frac{-f_2}{f_1}\\
g''=-\frac{f_{11}f_2^2-2f_{12}f_2 f_1+f_{22}f_1^2}{f_1^3} 
$$
For the example problem, $f_{11}=2$, $f_{12}=0$, and $f_{22}=0$, which leaves $g''=-\frac{2}{8g^3}=-\frac{1}{4 s^{3/2}} $.
So, again, what happens when you try to apply this to the Newton iteration, now taking the second derivative of $F$ rt $s$ -- but treating $g_0$ as a constant:
$$
\frac {d}{ds}F(g_0,s)=\frac{f f_{12}-f_1 f_2}{f_1^2} \\
\frac {d^2}{ds^2}F(g_0,s)=\frac{f_2 f_{12} + f f_{122} -f_{12} f_2 - f_1 f_{22}}{f_1^2} - 2 f_{12} \frac{f f_{12}-f_1 f_2}{f_1^3}\\
\text{Using }f=0\\
\frac {d^2}{ds^2}F(g_0,s)=\frac{- f_1^2 f_{22} + 2 f_{12} f_1 f_2}{f_1^3}
$$
That's not quite the same answer as we got from the implicit method! This would output $0$ for your example problem.
What if we have two iterations of the algorithm, instead? Let's call that double-iteration function $G$, and see how it differentiates wrt $s$: $$
G(g_0,s)=F(g_0,s)-\frac{f(F(g_0,s),s)}{f_1(F(g_0,s),s)}\\
G(g_0,s)=F-\frac{f(F,s)}{f_1(F,s)}\\
\frac{d}{ds}G=
  \frac{f(F,s)f_{11}(F,s)F'+f(F,s) f_{12}(F,s) -f_1(F,s) f_2(F,s)}{f_1(F,s)^2}
$$
Since $f(F,s)$ evaluates to $0$, and $F=g_0$ numerically, we can see that the first order behavior of $G$ is the same as that of $F$ -- the calculated first derivative doesn't change from adding another iteration. Taking another derivative:
$$
\frac{d^2}{ds^2}G=
  \frac{
f_1(F,s)^2f_{11}(F,s)F'^2
+f_1(F,s) f_{111}(F,s)f(F,s) F'^2
+f_1(F,s) f_{112}(F,s) f(F,s) F'
+f(F,s) f_1(F,s) f_{11}(F,s)F''
+f(F,s) f_1(F,s) f_{121}(F,s)F'
+f(F,s) f_1(F,s) f_{122}(F,s)
-f_1(F,s)^2 f_{22}(F,s)
}{f_1(F,s)^3}
-2   \frac{f(F,s)f_{11}(F,s)^2F'^2+f(F,s) f_{11}(F,s)f_{12}(F,s)) F' -f_1(F,s) f_2(F,s)f_{11}(F,s)F' }{f_1(F,s)^3} 
-2   \frac{f(F,s)f_{11}(F,s) f_{12}(F,s) F'+f(F,s) f_{12}(F,s)^2 -f_1(F,s) f_2(F,s)f_{12}(F,s)}{f_1(F,s)^3}
$$
This is a mess and I may have made a mistake... But simplifying again by setting $f(F,s)=0$: $$
\frac{d^2}{ds^2}G=
  \frac{
f_1(F,s)f_{11}(F,s)F'^2
-f_1(F,s) f_{22}(F,s)
+  2 f_2(F,s)f_{11}(F,s)F' +  2 f_2(F,s)f_{12}(F,s) }{f_1(F,s)^2}
$$
And then applying $F'=\frac{-f_2(g_0,s)}{f_1(g_0,s)}$, and the fact that numerically $f_1(F,s)=f_1(g_0,s)$ etc...:$$
\frac{d^2}{ds^2}G=
  \frac{
f_1 f_{11} \frac{f_2^2}{f_1^2}
-f_1 f_{22}
-  2 f_2 f_{11} \frac{f_2}{f_1} +  2 f_2 f_{12} }{f_1^2}=
 \frac{
-f_{11} f_2^2
-f_1^2 f_{22}
 +  2 f_1 f_2 f_{12} }{f_1^3}
$$
Which lines up with the implicit solution for $g''$!
I think if you do more iterations, you'll continue getting the same first and second derivative -- but I don't know how to show that.
Furthermore, I would caution against assuming that the number of iterations gives you the corresponding order of derivative approximation. For example, if you were trying to get a 3rd or 4th order sensitivity, it's not obvious that you would need 3 or 4 iterations, respectively.

Note: this type of method is often referred to as "adjoint sensitivity" which is a slightly different concept than what OP is referring to, which is "forward-mode sensitivity." Both compute sensitivities correctly via the chain rule, but the difference between adjoints and forward-mode is essentially in what order you do the matrix multiplication within the chain rule. Adjoints are used more often for large problems because the cost is a fixed number of forward model evaluations.

Thanks, this is great. This is exactly the lines on which I was also working but like you encountered a bit of messy algebra , and discovered I needed the double iteration. I will reconcile this against my own notes. Many thanks.
